# How do I make my DIVs travel in my Tetris game?

Tags: javascript, html, tetris

Okay, I don't really know how to word this question, but basically here is my code for my Tetris game:

```
var currentPiece=Math.floor(Math.random()*7)+1

switch(currentPiece){
    case 1: //O
        var filler =  document.getElementById('1.5')
        filler.style.backgroundColor= 'yellow';
        var filler =  document.getElementById('1.6')
        filler.style.backgroundColor= 'yellow';
        var filler =  document.getElementById('2.5')
        filler.style.backgroundColor= 'yellow';
        var filler =  document.getElementById('2.6')
        filler.style.backgroundColor= 'yellow';
        break;
```

And my HTML

```
<body> 
    <div class="display">
        <div id="holdSection">HOLD</div>
        <div id="board">
        <div id="1.1" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="1.2" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="1.3" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="1.4" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="1.5" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="1.6" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="1.7" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="1.8" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="1.9" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="1.10" class="cell"></div>

        <div id="2.1" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="2.2" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="2.3" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="2.4" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="2.5" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="2.6" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="2.7" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="2.8" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="2.9" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="2.10" class="cell"></div>

        <div id="3.1" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="3.2" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="3.3" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="3.4" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="3.5" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="3.6" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="3.7" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="3.8" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="3.9" class="cell"></div>
        <div id="3.10" class="cell"></div>
```

What i want to do is two things:

1. Be able to manipulate the produced yellow squares that are in the divs to move to other divs
2. Have some sort of identifier to indicate whether or not the div is filled with a color or if it is empty

Open to any suggestions, not even sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: Rather than manipulating `style.backgroundColor` directly, it would be better to add/remove a class name (e.g. `filler.classList.add('filled')`) to indicate a square is filled or empty. To test whether it is full or empty, use `filler.classList.contains('filled')`. As for "moving" the squares, that's just a matter of removing the 'filled' class from one div and adding it to another.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any idea how i can manipulate the position of the filled squares to move to other positions?

Comment: If you want to move a filled div "down", you need to remove the 'filled' class name from it and add the 'filled' class name to the div that is below it. So you need to write a helper function that takes a given div and determines which div is above, below, to the left, and to the right.

Comment: Thank you, so currently, the yellow squares are set individually, and move individually, do you know how I can group them together for them to operate as a unit?

Comment: Give them each group a common `data-id` attribute, e.g. `<div id="2.1" class="cell" data-id="1">/div>` and `<div id="2.1" class="cell" data-id="1">/div>`. Then, to select every div in that group, look for all the divs with a `data-id` value of 1 with `document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="1"]')`.